# Chaptering bibliography using bibtex, in EQ style memoir latex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, memoir

I am writing my thesis in `memoir` style in Latex. I use the `EQ style` that I found in a simple google search. The style is pretty good, but only works using `openleft` and has many issues that escape from my comprehension.

My main problem is that when I use that style, the bibliography is not generated as a Chapter, or at least it doesn't look like a chapter, it doesn't appear any heading. 
I don't know how to make it count as a final chapter, or at least that it appears as a header. I have attached an example code of what I am saying.

```
\documentclass[openleft]{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\copypagestyle{EQ-pagestyle}{companion}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{.382\foremargin}
\makerunningwidth{EQ-pagestyle}{\headwidth}
\makeheadposition{EQ-pagestyle}{flushright}{flushleft}{}{}
\makeevenhead{EQ-pagestyle}{\normalfont\bfseries\thepage}{}            
{\normalfont\bfseries\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{EQ-pagestyle}{\normalfont\bfseries\rightmark}{}{\normalfont\bfseries\thepage}
\newif\ifNoChapNum
\makeatletter
% chapterpage layout
\copypagestyle{EQ-chapterstyle}{EQ-pagestyle}
\makeheadposition{EQ-chapterstyle}{flushright}{flushleft}{}{}
\makeevenhead{EQ-chapterstyle}{%
\normalfont\bfseries\thepage}{}{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne%
\ifNoChapNum%
\raisebox{-4.5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\chapnamefont \rightmark}%
\else%
\raisebox{-4.5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\chapnamefont\@chapapp\ \thechapter}%
\fi%
\else%
\raisebox{-4.5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\chapnamefont\rightmark}%
\fi%
}
\makeoddhead{EQ-chapterstyle}{\rightmark}{}{\normalfont\bfseries\thepage}
% build in the shorter headline
\@namedef{EQ-chapterstyleheadrule}{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne%
\ifNoChapNum%
\settowidth\@tempdimc{\quad\chapnamefont\rightmark}%
\else%
\settowidth\@tempdimc{\quad\chapnamefont\@chapapp\ \thechapter}%
\fi%
\else%
\settowidth\@tempdimc{\quad\chapnamefont\rightmark}%
\fi%
\setlength\@tempdimc{\headwidth-\@tempdimc}%
\hrule\@width \@tempdimc\@height \normalrulethickness \vskip-    
\normalrulethickness%
}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{EQ-chapterstyle}
\pagestyle{EQ-pagestyle}
\makechapterstyle{EQ}{
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\raggedleft\bfseries\huge}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne%
\ifNoChapNum\else\chaptitlefont ##1\fi%
\fi%
\ifNoChapNum%
\markboth{##1}{##1}%
\fi%
\afterpage{\global\NoChapNumfalse}%
 }
 \renewcommand\afterchapternum{}
 \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne%
\ifNoChapNum\else\par\nobreak\vskip\afterchapskip\fi%
\fi}
\setlength\beforechapskip{15pt}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{\global\NoChapNumtrue}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\raggedleft\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{EQ}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
Some text at the beginning of a chapter. And we add a lot of text to
make sure that it spans more than one line.
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter title}
Some text at the beginning of a chapter. And we add a lot of text to
make sure that it spans more than one line.
\chapter*{A non-numbered chapter title}
Some text at the beginning of a chapter. And we add a lot of text to
make sure that it spans more than one line.
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
 \bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
 21.479.}  1991.
 \bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973:
 Random House, N.Y.
\bibitem{norman} E. H. Norman {\em Japan's emergence as a modern
  state} 1940: International Secretariat, Institute of Pacific
  Relations.

 \bibitem{fo} Bob Tadashi Wakabayashi {\em Anti-Foreignism and Western
 Learning in Early-Modern Japan} 1986: Harvard University Press.

 \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! There is a semi-official version of this style included in the [Memoir Chapter styles document](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles?lang=en) with the remark that it was a little hard to get it to work.  Is that version better for you?

Comment: Your code prints a bibliography section, following the style you have programed for chapter headings.